# How to make a particular change in all the keys of a hash?

Tags: perl

I have a hash which is like this:

```
   'IRQ_VSAFE_LPM_ASC_0' => '140',
   'IRQ_VSAFE_LPM_ASC_1' => '141'.......and so on
```

I want to replace ASC_ by ASC_1 in all keys in the hash. I tried this:

```
foreach $_(keys $hash)   
{ 
s/ASC_/ASC_1/g; 
}
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to delete old keys from the hash and insert new ones,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub rename_keys {

  my ($hash, $func) = @_;

  my @k1 = my @k2 = keys %$hash;
  $func->() for @k2;
  @$hash{@k2} = delete @$hash{@k1};
}

my %hash = (
 'IRQ_VSAFE_LPM_ASC_0' => '140',
 'IRQ_VSAFE_LPM_ASC_1' => '141',
);
rename_keys(\%hash, sub { s/ASC_/ASC_1/ });
```

Comment: Its working fine . Thankyou so much :)  I am trying to understand how it is working . I am not getting this line  $func->() for @k2 . Rest I understood . Do you mind elaborating ?

Comment: @Grace90 it is a [`foreach modifier`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers); you could also write it like `for (@k2) { $func->() }`. `$func` is anonymous function which is provided as second argument and operates on `$_`, thus changing/substituting all elements of `@k2` array.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer addressed a way to do what you want. However, it also makes sense to explain why what you tried to do didn't work.

The problem is that the syntax used for working with hashes in Perl can mislead you with its simplicity compared to the actual way the hash works underneath.

What you see in Perl code is simply two pieces of information: a hash key and a corresponding hash value: `$myHash{$key} = $value;` or even more misleading `%myHash = ($key => $value);`

However, the way the hashes work, this isn't merely storing the key and a value as a pair, as the code above may lead you into thinking. Instead, a hash is a complicated data structure, in which the key serves as an input into the addressing which is done via a formula (hash function) and an algorithm (to deal with collistions) - the details are well covered on [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

As such, changing a hash key as if it was merely a value isn't enough, because what is stored in the hash isn't just a value - it's a whole data structure with addressing based on that value. Therefore when you change a hash key, it would ALSO change the location of the value in the data structure, and doing that isn't possible without removing the old entry and adding a brand new entry under a new key, which will delete and re-insert the value in the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this may be to use `pairmap` from recent `List::Util`.

```
use 5.014;  # so we can use the /r flag to s///
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my %new = pairmap { ($a =~ s/ASC_/ASC_1/r) => $b } %oldhash;
```